# Jquery click event works on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to format the users input in the textarea, where extra spaces and enters are replaced with single spaces fortunately this part works, however only on the 2nd click of the button. I want to know what's wrong and how to fix this:

Here's my code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EnXp7/

Html

```
<textarea type="text" id="address" onfocus="if(this.value===this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==='')this.value=this.defaultValue">
   Input Address Here
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="Validate" value="Validate" onClick="valbtn()">
```

Jquery/Javascript

```
function valbtn() {
    $("#Validate").click(function () {
        $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
    });
    var x = document.getElementById("address").value;
    if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
        alert("No Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jS66P/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function `valbtn()` gets called on the first click and binds your validation to click again. So you'll have to click again before actually running that validation.

If you keep calling `valbtn()` onclick, modify the function like that:

```
function valbtn() {

    // Run it instead of binding it to the click event
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g,' '));

    var x = document.getElementById("address").value;
    if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
        alert("No Input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning a second click handler inside the click function.

Delete the `onClick` attribute from you HTML and in Javascript replace your current code with just this:

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Validate").click(function() {
            $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
            var x = document.getElementById("address").value;
            if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
                alert("No Input");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and totally remove the onclick event in your input:

```
<input type="button" id="Validate" value="Validate">
```

With JQuery you dont need that.

You have an action listener in an action listener or in other words you mixed jQuery and JavaScript I suggest you drop the JavaScript call as desribed above and do a pure JQUery action listener which is more clear and easy to use.

It will also take care about browser compatiblity for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should move

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
});
```

outside of the `valbtn` function:

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    if (valbtn()) {
        $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
    }
});
```

I also made `valbtn` return boolean indicating if processing is needed or not:

```
function valbtn() {
    var x = $("#address").value;
    if (x === "" || x === "Input Address Here") {
        alert("No Input");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/EnXp7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put your jquery script out side  valbtn() function. no need create function use only

below code

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g,' '));
});
```